# Masonry.js libraby breaks css at the bottom of site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

As the title says entire bottom part of the site breaks on mobile(for example samsung galaxy s5 mini). It only happens in mozzila mobile broswer(here is a screenshot). Does anyone know why is masonry causing this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFSKw.png

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the float isn't cleared after the tiles have been rendered.

See: https://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/